# Django rest framework w/ no models - can't route to detail view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Following [this](https://medium.com/django-rest-framework/django-rest-framework-viewset-when-you-don-t-have-a-model-335a0490ba6f) tutorial, I'm trying to add a url to which one could make a POST request without a model:

```
router.register(r'send_message', SendMessageViewSet, base_name='send_message')
```

I don't need a GET, but I added one for debugging purposes:

```
class SendMessageViewSet(ViewSet):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return Response(HTTP_200_OK)

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   ...
```

Yet I'm able to get the "list" (url with no pk) but not the specific resource.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you want to use a viewset for this; if you only want to support POST, why not a standalone view?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'm new to django and I was just blindly following the tutorial. I don't need a viewset. I'm not sure what's the difference between the View and the Viewset classes.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have missed my link to the full repository.
You are doomed because you are overriding `get` instead of `list`.

See https://github.com/linovia/drf-demo/blob/master/drf_demo/model_less/views.py for a full working example.